# Using jquery to affect divs with same id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have more than 1 div with the same id, and I'm trying to use jquery to affect all of them at the same time, as oppose to just the first div. Is there a way to do this without changing the div id?

```
<div id = '1'>
<div id = '1'>
<div id = '1'>

//codes
document.getElementById(1).innerHTML = data;
$("#"+1).hide();
$("#"+1).fadeIn(500);
//codes
```

Comment: That's what classes are for. If you can't change the html, then try `$('div[id=1]')`

Comment: $("div[id='1']") but don't do that.

Comment: @unpollo You're suggesting it, but you're saying to not use it? I don't understand.

Comment: use classes instead of id
document.getElementsByClassName("1").innerHTML = data;

Comment: @jessica you cannot have multiple same IDs in one HTML document. It isn't valid.

Comment: ***ID should always be unique***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id is supposed to be unique.  Instead use a class.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".fader").html("testing");
  $(".fader").hide();
  $(".fader").fadeIn(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fader">test</div>
<div class="fader">test</div>
<div class="fader">test</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, the id attribute should be unique throughout the entire document. There should never be 2 elements having the same id attribute value.

What you need to do is use a class, which can be used on many elements throughout the html document.

```
<div class="theClassName"></div>
<div class="theClassName"></div>
<div class="theClassName"></div>

var elementsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("theClassName");
for(var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
    var element = elementsArray[i];
    // do something with each element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Attr selector` can resolve your problem.

```
$('[id='1']')
```

But that is very not recommend, because the `id` attr is design to be unique.Instead of that, you can use `class` or `name` attr.

```
<div class='someClass' name='someName'>
<div class='someClass'>
<div class='someClass'>

// using class
$('.someClass').hide();

// using name
$('div[name='someName']').hide();
```